# Wordpress and custom fields in a loop

Tags: php, wordpress

Say I have custom fields with the keys `p_title_1` `p_value_1` `p_title_2` `p_value_2`

Each of these has values within them and I would like to loop through `p_title_[i]` and `p_value_[i]` and show them on the page so that title and value would be grouped together in their own div.

I can't seem to figure out how to write it as a loop to show the 1's together and 2's together.

Reason it needs to be in a loop is incase more custom fields get added in the future. At current I have the following but it only echos the key and value

```
<?php
                 $custom_fields = get_post_custom( get_the_ID() );
                 $my_custom_field = $custom_fields['p_title_1'];
                 foreach ( $my_custom_field as $key => $value )
                    echo $key . " => " . $value . "<br />";
                 ?>
```

Help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use the field name to build an array.

Where the array looks like:

```
array
 1 => 
    array 
      'title' => 'title 1' 
      'value' => 'value 1'
```

Loop through your fields and add to the array:

You can get the array index using explode function

```
$parts = explode ( '_' , $fieldname  );

$name = $parts[0];
$index = $parts[1];
```

And add the value to the array:

```
$array[$index][$name] = $value;
```